# Скопировать текст из поля ввода в буфер обмена

Tags: скрипт, html, css, javascript

Прошу подсказать скрипт, позволяющий скопировать текст из поля ввода в буфер обмена, при нажатии на ссылку/кнопку.

Comment: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/javascript-copy-to-clipboard.html   
https://waaave.com/tutorial/jquery/copy-text-to-clipboard-using-jquery/

Comment: Цитирую (вторая ссылка):  

  > Well, there's a trick for that, which is using Flash: ZeroClipboard

Первая ссылка то же самое. + Код для IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Копировать в буфер позволяет только IE. Для других браузеров можно использовать flash.

Хотя если быть совсем уж точным, то некоторые версии браузеров все-таки позволяют копировать текст в буфер с помощью javascript. Однако пользователю при этом будет показываться предупреждение.

Comment: или как в линуксе - копировать===выделить